# Double (nested) FOR loop in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I am trying to write a double For loop in R, but for the following code the output is not what I need

```
k<-4
n<-5


for (i in 1:n) 
 for (j in 1:k+1) 
  cat(i,j, "\n")
```

Output:

```
> for (i in 1:n) 
+  for (j in 1:k+1) 
+   cat(i,j, "\n")
1 2 
1 3 
1 4 
1 5 
2 2 
2 3 
2 4 
2 5 
3 2 
3 3 
3 4 
3 5 
4 2 
4 3 
4 4 
4 5 
5 2 
5 3 
5 4 
5 5
```

Why does *j* start with 2?

Comment: Try for(j in 1:(k+1)). 1:k+1 makes the vector (1:k) and then adds 1 to each item

Comment: Order or operations -- compare `1:4 + 1` with `(1:4) + 1` in your console

Answer (score 2):

The +1 after k is adding to j, try

```
for (j in 1:(k+1))
```

to force the addition to happen to k

Comment: Thank you so much. This was such a silly mistake